# Elasticsearch query a specific time range

Tags: elasticsearch

Helllo,

I would like to apply a range of 7 days at the query of the elasticsearch. Currently the following which is for 1 hour and it works, but I want to get the current time and set a time range of 7 days.

```
          "range": {
            "@timestamp": {
              "format": "strict_date_optional_time",
              "gte": "2021-01-26T05:45:58.140Z",
              "lte": "2021-01-26T06:45:58.140Z"
            }
          }
        }
```

I tried the following for having it for 1 day, but it didn't produce the right results.

```
            "date": {
              "gte": "now-1d",
              "lte": "now"
            }
          }
        }
```

Comment: Can you post your index structure, please?

Comment: do you mean to append the full body request?@EvaldasBuinauskas

Comment: Appending the whole request would be helpful, but I meant `GET http://your-es-host:9200/index-name`, this will show index structure, paste it here.

Comment: sorry but it's too long and has information that cannot be posted here. Is there any other info that may help you?

Comment: Well, my gut feeling is that you're querying the wrong field. Your first query uses `@timestamp` field, the other one uses `date`. But that didn't seem like a sophisticated answer without knowing more details.

Comment: actually there is no date field, but how can I use the 7-day filter instead of using actual dates (2021-01-26T05:45:58.140Z) ?

Comment: `"gte": "now-7d"` is correct and should work, the field you're querying against obviously must be indexed as `date` for it to work. 

However, I'd suggest not using `now` and instead passing datetime string from your application, this way you'll queries will be more cacheable.